# HTML after label radio button (depending on radio button)

Tags: 7, theming, forms

I need to add some html to specific radio buttons. This is a picture to clarify what I'm looking for:

[image]

As you can see I want to add some text to the options. These are radio buttons where you can select one option. This is what I have now:

[image]

I've tried adding html with the [theme_radio function](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/theme_radio/7) with suffix like this:

```
function ppprogram_radio($variables) {
    $element = $variables['element'];
    $element['#attributes']['type'] = 'radio';
    $element['#suffx'] = "<p>just testing</p>";

    element_set_attributes($element, array('id', 'name','#return_value' => 'value'));

    if (isset($element['#return_value']) && $element['#value'] !== FALSE && $element['#value'] == $element['#return_value']) {
        $element['#attributes']['checked'] = 'checked';
    }
    _form_set_class($element, array('form-radio'));

    return '<input' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . ' />';
}
```

But that didn't do anything ... . I've also tried adding html to the return but then it's added before my label and I want it after my label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this will help. please follow the comments.

```
 function CUSTOMMODULENAME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
        if($form_id=='YOUR FORM ID'){
           /* uncomment the following code after updating the key variables<field machine name> and check out the option keys.
           */
           // echo '<pre>';
           // print_r($form['<field machine name>']['und']['#options']);
           //exit;
            $form['<field machine name>']['und']['#options']['<key>'] .= '<h3>Hello World </h3>'; 
            // the above code will add <h3>Hello World </h3> alone with the existing radio button label
//Remove the comments if it helps.
        }

    }
```

Let me know if you need any additional clarity.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks! It works, what would be the best solution. This one or the previous answer of wolverine?

Answer (score 0):

'suffx' is misspelled on line 4. Does it work if you correct the spelling?

```
 $element['#suffix'] = "<p>just testing</p>";
```

Comment: no, still nothing ..

Answer (score 0):

Implement `theme_form_element_label($variables)` in your `template.php` and append your value to the returning label.